# Patterns to compensate for lack of runtime method lookup based on polymorphic args in Java?

Tags: java, polymorphism, listener

It seems that Java can't choose the most appropriate method implementation based on the runtime type of an argument, as documented [here](http://www.rizzoweb.com/java/polymorphismAndOverloading.html). Recapitulating the example:

```
class Superclass {}
class Subclass extends Superclass {}
class Test {
    public void aMethod(Superclass s) {...}
    public void aMethod(Subclass s) {...}
}
```

Which method of the Test class is executed is determined based on the type of the reference, not the type of the instance. Again, based on the linked examples:

```
Test aTest = new Test();
Superclass aSuper = new Subclass();
test.aMethod(aSuper);
```

It is `aMethod(Superclass s)` that executes, not `aMethod(Subclass s)`.

I was trying to create a variation on the listener pattern, where listeners 'plug in' via an interface, and the listeners have methods defined for subclasses of the interfaces.

As a quick example of what I mean, say I'm building an alarm clock that can have functionality plugged in.

The implementation for the above I had in mind would look like an interface `Event`, with a subclass `WakeUpEvent`, and an interface `EventListener` requiring implementation of `handle(Event evt)`.

I hoped to create a class implementing a no-op `handle(Event evt)` with a specific `handle(WakeUpEvent evt)` if the listener wanted to deal with that type of event.

Of course, this approach won't work as-is - the obvious solution is runtime `instanceof` checks - yuk.

Are there any patterns or approaches that I can use to get the behaviour I want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These situations are when I think of Visitor or double dispatch pattern.

Comment: Nice one, very helpful - never heard of double dispatch before. I think I see how to implement Visitor to solve this problem... do you know, is this one of those scenarios that other languages are able to solve more elegantly?

Comment: Double dispatch is used in C++ (Scott Meyers "More Effective C++"), Java, and C#.  I think that most of the object-oriented design patterns are superfluous in functional languages.

Comment: @Brabster: All languages which have multiple dispatch, e.g. Common Lisp, Dylan, Clojure, Slate. Martin Odersky hinted that some future versions of Scala might also implement multiple dispatch.

Answer (score 7):

Visitor pattern is what you need

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, you could use a Visitor pattern.

However, I would encourage you to think about an alternative approach as this all seems like a design smell to me.

Shouldn't aMethod actually be defined in SuperClass rather than Test? Then you can override aMethod in the SubClass, and the correct version will be called at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a direct answer but more a hint to understand the problem.

What you describe is a confusing mix of method overloading (used in the `Test` class) from overriding (used to describe what you want to achieve by implementing `EventListener` but then overloading `handle`).

The reason for this behaviour is that overloading results in a compile-time decision which method will be invoked. 
Thus, if you use overloading it is a good idea to have mutually incompatible argument types to avoid such confusion.