# How to call a polymorphic function from an agnostic function?

Tags: java, oop

I have a method `foo`

```
void foo (String x) { ... }
void foo (Integer x) { ... }
```

and I want to call it from a method which does not care about the argument:

```
void bar (Iterable i) {
  ...
  for (Object x : i) foo(x); // this is the only time i is used
  ...
}
```

the code above complains that that `foo(Object)` is not defined and when I add

```
void foo (Object x) { throw new Exception; }
```

then `bar(Iterable<String>)` calls that instead of `foo(String)` and throws the exception.

How do I avoid having two textually identical definitions of `bar(Iterable<String>)` and `bar(Iterable<Integer>)`?

I thought I would be able to get away with something like

```
<T> void bar (Iterable<T> i) {
  ...
  for (T x : i) foo(x); // this is the only time i is used
  ...
}
```

but then I get `cannot find foo(T)` error.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4086523/patterns-to-compensate-for-lack-of-runtime-method-lookup-based-on-polymorphic-ar

Answer (score 2):

The problem you are facing is that overloaded methods are bound at compile time. In your example, the compiler tries to figure out which of the `foo()` methods to call. However, the strongest static type of `x` in your example is Object, and there is not method `foo(Object)`, so the compiler says it can't call the appropriate method.

If you add the `foo(Object)` method, no matter what the actual runtime type of x is, you will always call the `foo(Object)` method.

This problem extends to using generics. Since `T` can be any type, you must have a generic method `foo(T)` or your code will not compile. However, if you add that method, you lose the ability to have these methods discern between the different argument types, because only `foo(T)` will be called.

The only way to work around this is by doing a case by case check and cast like the other answers proposed. Unless the argument types are classes you define and they can all implement a common interface. Then you can do something like:

```
interface ArgumentType {
   void callback(FooClass c);
}

class YourClassA implements ArgumentType {
    void callback( FooClass c ) {
         c.foo( this );
    }
}
```

`FooClass` would still have to have a `foo()` method for every implementing class of `ArgumentType`, but this way you can have your selection by type agnostic.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "strongest static type"? Thanks!

Comment: By "strongest static type" I mean the most specific type that the compiler can infer for your variable x. For example, in principle if you have this code:   Object x; x = new Integer(); foo(x); a smart compiler can figure out that the type of x at the call site is Integer and can call the appropriate method. In your example, that's not possible, because there is nothing to hint at the type in your code. Hence the "strongest" type the compiler knows is Object.

Answer (score 1):

Think of it this way: which version of `foo` should be called if `x` is an `Object`?

That's the problem faced by the JVM.

If you want a truly polymorphic method, then you need to explicitly write one. Such a method could then inspect the `Object` through introspection to see what it's actual class type is and call the appropriate method after that.

*Or*, you could take a close look at what `foo` does. Is it only calling methods defined by `Object`? If so, just create a `void foo(Object x)` method that does the necessaries.

Answer (score 1):

The trouble is you are trying to find `foo(Object x)` and while String and Integer are both Objects, not all Objects are either String or Integer, and java doesn't narrowcast to the right class.

I would perhaps suggest creating a method like:

```
void foo(Object o){
     if ( o instanceof String){
         String s = (String) o;
         //Deal with s
     } else if ( o instanceof Integer){
         Integer i = (Integer) o;
         //Deal with i
     }
}
```

Also, if you are using generics anyway, you shouldn't be passing a raw iterator in bar